# Caching a component's view for less than a minute

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, cache

I have a component which has a feed. This feed updates constantly, pulling information from external sources. To reduce pressure on my server at high traffic periods, I want to give the generated feed a cache of around 10 seconds, possibly less.

However, as far as I am aware, Joomla's cache time is global across all components and has a minimum time of a minute, even though modules will work in seconds and can be added on a module-by-module basis.

Is there any way to make a component view have a shorter cache time than this?

The only way I can think of is a cron job that deletes the cached files, which doesn't seem an ideal approach.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm told cron is limited to a minute, so that's probably also not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension called JotCache, which allows you to control caching at an extension level. Having said that, I recommend that you implement caching within the extension itself (it's not hard to do that).

Comment: This extension does not appear to allow a single view of a component to have a cache time in seconds, leaving the rest with a longer cache time.  It seems to just set a single cache time for everything, as per core global settings.   

The reason I can't implement caching in my extension, which I want to do, is that I need its feed view to work in seconds and not minutes, and that I need it to have a different cache time to all other components, ie to work how modules work.  Components don't seem to work like this, however.